# Trying to pass the parameter in a query in Node.js mssql

Tags: sql-server, node.js

I'm trying to query the table on some condition:

```
  try {
    var pool = await sql.connect(config);
    var data = await sql.query`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ${types}`;
  } catch (err) {
    res.send(err);
  }
```

Where types is "ContractType = 'AllRisks' "

For some reason it's not returning anything. When I put hardcode types string directly inside the sql.query then it actually returns results and works.

Not too sure what is happening.

I try the other way:

```
var result1 = await pool.request()
  .input('types', sql.VarChar(50), types)
  .query('SELECT * FROM dbo.denormalized WHERE @types');
```

And this doesn't work either.

Would really appreciate some help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First

> var data = await sql.query`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ${types}`;

Is missing parenthesis, so it isn't actually calling `.query`, but you really should be doing the second method anyways, for security (to prevent sql injection).

But the second way is probably throwing an error the way it is -

In sending a prepared statement, the sql has to be interpreted/understood without the @types literal being given - it considers it a parameter. `select * from x where 'hello world'` isn't valid sql, and everything within @types is being bound as a Varchar literal.

do

`SELECT * FROM dbo.denormalized WHERE ContractType = @types`

and make the javascript `types` variable only contain `AllRisks`. Note you will not need to escape the quotes around AllRisks, the value "AllRisks" as a string should be sufficient; e.g. `let types = 'AllRisks'`. You already told the library you were binding a Varchar.

--- Edit

Since you want to do an array of types, I looked into doing WHERE IN using the mssql package and turned up this related question - [NodeJS MSSQL WHERE IN Prepared SQL Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33390833/nodejs-mssql-where-in-prepared-sql-statement)

I would throw in the towel on using the mssql module directly at this point and use http://knexjs.org/ which is common, and uses mssql underneath the hood. It will handle this sort of thing for you with something like `knex.select().from('table').whereIn('ContractTypes', types)`.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me! The reasons I needed to concatenate the string in such a way because the number of contract types is dynamic. It might be several values. Wasn't sure how to do that and right now I'm just concatenating these multiple values

Comment: @Jack I updated the answer, there's a related question for helping with WHERE IN, and I would recommend using knex.js instead of going that route - looking at the answer its a little heavy.

Comment: Thanks! Just looked at knexjs and this is exactly what I've been looking for!