# I need to convert a javascript array to a sql list

Tags: sql, node.js, express

so i have this req -

```
app.delete("/delete/:sku", (req, res) => {
const sku = req.params.sku;
db.query(DELETE FROM products WHERE sku IN(?)
```

the console.log(req.params.sku) results in - `wefwefwef,erferferfrgrwb,23r23r` on the console,

i need to convert the sku string to a SQL list so i can insert the values for the IN clause.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NodeJS MSSQL WHERE IN Prepared SQL Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33390833/nodejs-mssql-where-in-prepared-sql-statement)

Comment: Ty for the help i found the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a parameterized query. This could look something like this.

```js
const sku = req.params.sku.split(',');
const ins = new Array(sku.length).fill('?').join();
db.query(`DELETE FROM products WHERE sku IN (${ins})`, sku);
```

If you need to give the params names like `@p1`, then something like this

```js
const sku = req.params.sku.split(',');
const ins = sku.map((_, i) => `@p${i}`).join();
db.query(`DELETE FROM products WHERE sku IN (${ins})`, sku);
```

Comment: Aw man it worked you are a blessing, ty for helping!